# How to animate the transition between button states?

Tags: android, android-animation

I need to create a style for a custom button (tri-state), but I need to have an animation making a smooth transition between states.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape android:shape="rectangle"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <corners android:radius="8dp" />
    <stroke android:color="#CED2D4" android:width="1dp" />
    <solid android:color="#EDEEEF"/>

</shape>
```

When the user press this button it should transition to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape android:shape="rectangle"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <corners android:radius="8dp" />
    <stroke android:color="#f57f17" android:width="1dp" />
    <solid android:color="#EDEEEF"/>

</shape>
```

And when active (selected):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape android:shape="rectangle"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <corners android:radius="8dp" />
    <stroke android:color="#bdbdbd" android:width="1dp" />
    <solid android:color="#e0e0e0"/>

</shape>
```

As you can see I'm changing the stroke and background color. But I want to animate this color change. How can I do it?

Comment: you can use animated-selector, but it is available after api21

Comment: or `TransitionDrawable`

Comment: @MikhailKim target API is 23, but min is 15. I tried to use `TransitionDrawable' too, however the animation seems to repeat even when set to another